# UTF-8 - Oracle issue

Tags: perl, oracle, utf-8

I set my NLS_LANG variable as 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8' in the perl file that connects to oracle and tries to insert the data.

However when I insert a record with one value having this 'ñ' character the sql fails.
But if I use 'Ñ' it inserts just fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Additional info:
If I change my NLS_LANG to 'AMERICAN_AMERICA.UTF8' I can insert 'ñ' just fine...

Answer (score 1):

What does it fail with ?

Generally if there is a problem in character conversion it fails quietly (eg recording a character with an inappropriate translation). Sometimes you get an error which indicates that the column isn't large enough. This is typically when trying to store, for example, a character that takes up two or three bytes in a column that only allows one byte.

First step is to confirm the database settings

```
select * from V$NLS_PARAMETERS where parameter like ‘%CHARACTERSET%’;
```

Then check the byte composition of the strings with a:

```
select dump('ñ',16), dump('Ñ',16) from dual;
```

Comment: Looks like this question is going to be closed as duplicate of the newer question [DBD::Oracle and utf8 issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016128/dbdoracle-and-utf8-issue). Just in case you're interested :)

Answer (score 0):

The first query gives me:

```
1   NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
2   NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
```

The second query gives me:

```
1   Typ=96 Len=2: c3,b1 Typ=96 Len=2: c3,91
```

My exact db and perl settings are listed in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016128/dbdoracle-and-utf8-issue

Comment: Why are you posting the same question three times?

Comment: Because I'm not getting any answers and I wanted to extent the description a bit.

Comment: please edit the original question, rather than posting again. All your questions are likely to be closed and deleted now.